# django static files not working

Tags: python, django

For some reason, django is not serving up my static files.

I have already looked at a bunch of fixes for this problem, but I still have not found a solution.

Here is my configuration:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', index),
    (r'^ajax/$', ajax),
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'static')}),
)
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/aurora/Code/django/test/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

When I navigate to `http://localhost:8000/static/css/default.css`
I get this error: `'css/default.css' could not be found`

When I navigate to `http://localhost:8000/static/`
I get this error: `Directory indexes are not allowed here.`

It looks like the static directory is getting mapped out, but the sub-directories are not.

Comment: Please see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168187/django-cannot-find-my-media-files-on-development-server/9168404#9168404 . Long and short, you don't store your static files in `STATIC_ROOT`. Django *never* uses this directory in development. Even in production, it's your webserver not Django that serves out of this directory.

Comment: Worked right away. post as an answer if you want me to mark as answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you need your static path in urls.py, remove that and it should work.

currently it is like this

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', index),
    (r'^ajax/$', ajax),
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'static')}),
)
```

just remove the r'^static line

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', index),
    (r'^ajax/$', ajax),
)
```

at least this is how it is done in django 1.3 and up

Comment: Still doesnt work, and when I go to http://localhost:8000/static/, I get an error with urls.py: "The current URL, static/, didn't match any of these."

Comment: is 'django.contrib.staticfiles', in your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

Comment: Yes. I also added my INSTALLED_APPS portion of settings.py to the question.

Comment: try this url, http://localhost:8000/static/css/default.css the other should not be accessible normally

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15578/discussion-between-vaibhav-mishra-and-franz-payer)

Comment: can you check chatroom and apply suggestion

Answer (score 18):

**In development:**

- `STATICFILES_DIRS` should have all static directories inside which all static files are resident
- `STATIC_URL` should be `/static/` if your files are in the local machine otherwise put the base URL here e.g. "http://example.com/"
- `INSTALLED_APPS` should include `'django.contrib.staticfiles'`

In the template, load the staticfiles module:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
..
..
<img src='{% static "images/test.png" %}' alt='img' />
```

**In Production:**

- Add `STATIC_ROOT` that is used by Django to collect all static files from `STATICFILES_DIRS` to it
- Collect static files

```sh
python manage.py collectstatic [--noinput]
```

- add the path to urls.py

```py
from . import settings
    ..
    ..
urlpatterns = patterns('',
..
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root':settings.STATIC_ROOT)}),)`
```

More detailed articles are listed below:

http://blog.xjtian.com/post/52685286308/serving-static-files-in-django-more-complicated

http://agiliq.com/blog/2013/03/serving-static-files-in-django/

Comment: Thank you. This summarizes the changes for dev and production quite well . 
In my case i had typed STATICFILES_DIR instead of STATICFILES_DIRS and had been struggling to get it to work

Answer (score 7):

Try running `python manage.py collectstatic` and see where the static files are being collected.

Add this to your `urls.py` and set `DEBUG=True` in `settings.py`

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
             (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes':True}),
         )

    urlpatterns += patterns('',
            (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes':True}),
        )
```

Comment: 0 static files copied to '/home/aurora/Code/django/test/static/'.

I did an ls on the directory and I can see the files there...

Comment: 'show_indexes':True should help you show list the indexes on `/static`. What do you see there?

Comment: The directory gets listed when I go to /static/, but I cannot access files in the directory

Comment: Does `localhost:8000/admin/` have all the `css` files?

Comment: Try editing your settings.py to below static section and copy your css under the `project_static` folder and then run `the `collectstatic` command

Comment: List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
        'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',

        'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',

       
        )



#From the django.contrib.staticfiles package, to store all static application media (Non -user generated)

STATIC_URL = "/static/"


STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(DIRNAME ,'static')



STATICFILES_DIRS = (

    os.path.join(DIRNAME , 'project_static'),

)

Answer (score 4):

You can do such settings like

1. Inside settings.py add static directory path

   ```
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        BASE_DIR / "static"
    ]
   ```

   Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/
2. add a line of code in urls.py

   ```
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
   ```

Comment: NameError: name 'staticfiles_urlpatterns' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/' 
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
```

Comment: You should add some explanation. Code-only answers are likely to get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following setup: (in Apr 2021)

- macos big sure
- vscode
- Ananconda 3 (for environment)

When I am trying to access my static files in Django using `http://localhost:8000/static/test.txt` if inside static folder a test.txt file exists.

1. open the `setting.py` file in your main project folder then
2. Paste this code inside `settings.py` at last:

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Added Manually
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]
```

Then restart VS Code.

Comment: Avoid posting your code in images, post it in a text format instead!

Comment: Ok sir, Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I'll do it

Comment: how can it run without a static root ??

Answer (score 0):

Here main directory name is mysite, and the app name is polls(polling_app project Django tutorial).

1. Create a static folder inside the main folder( mysite ).
2. We can add static files(such as JavaScript, imagefile, css etc) in static folder.
3. After creating static folder we have to inform Django on this by adding below line in settings.py(below the line       STATIC_URL = ‘/static/’)

1. STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

#Now tell django to look where for the static files you have added.
#on top of settings.py file add import os

2. STATICFILES_DIRS =
   [

   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysite/static/')

]

#Run this command in terminal to collect all static files in our     project.

3. python manage.py collectstatic

#Run the server, add port number if needed.

4. python manage.py runserver portnumber

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Remember the name STATICFILES_DIRS not anything else it is case sensitive

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35146218)